# React-Redux Fetch data from api, search and lazy loading

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a list of data which are rendered by default (20 items) with lazy loading functionality (pagination) to load more data when the user scrolls to a certain position.

Now I need to implement a search functionality from the api itself, my question is:

Initially I have 20 items, when a user search they will get another 20 items based on the search term (the old set will be replaced), and when scrolling they will get page 2 from the list based on the search term.

So what is the best practice here to know when I need to concatenate the old data with the new batch or to replace the old set of data with a new one.

My question is more architectural, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because backend shall has paginator in search, you only would re render component with new information in such page(bit collection), in other words , if you has service backend pagination render "item component", if you search into a collection(javascript array) in browser , use "collection/list component" (map), you can use [keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) to property change